# how to add css for aria-describedby

Tags: html, css

Hi I have the following checkbox and this checkbox should turn red border when the tool tip is shown.
The tool tip will show when clicked on submit button when the checkbox is not checked. So I want to show the user the red border for this checkbox.

[image]

The html is as below before clicking on submit button

[image]

And after clicking the submit button the html is as below.

[image]

Only the below piece of code is automatically added when tool tip is shown.

```
data-original-title title aria-describedby="Tooltip311812"
```

How to add css for "aria-describedby" and make the checkbox as red border when the tool tip is displayed. Here the Tooltip value is getting dynamically changed on every new reload of the page.
for eg : Tooltip311812, Tooltip678934 etc.

I am trying to find the solution and learn in the process. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[aria-describedby="value"]` as your selector.

```css
input[aria-describedby="test"] {
  border: 10px solid black;
}

input[aria-describedby="finished"] {
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input aria-describedby="test">
<input aria-describedby="finished">
```

Comment: I tried as below 
input[aria-describedby="Tooltip311812"] {
border: 1px solid red;
}

.
But the issue is that , there is random Tooltip value getting generated for the aria-describedby.
Now when I reloaded the page and check the value is "tooltip283063". Could you please suggest how to use css for dynamically changing values for aria-describedby.

Comment: Check this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) `input[aria-describedby^=value]` you can use something like this for example

Comment: Just like @Sfili_81 stated, this should do it: `input[aria-describedby^=Tooltip]` or `input[aria-describedby*=Tooltip]`@Mahi